# Python mapped lists is returning dictionaries out of order

Tags: python-3.x

I'll attach the entire code in the end, but now I'll go to the point.

I have this function which gets a title and price (str), and puts it on a dict

```
def create_dict(elem):
    title = ...
    price = ...

    print(title) # to check if it's fine 
    print(price, '\n') # same

    return {title, price}
```

This function is mapping a list, then it's printed on screen

```
data = map(
    create_dict,
    result_row_list
)

pprint(list(data))
```

As you can see, the dict should be like this {'title': 'price'}. but sometime, it gets inversed

This is from 'prints'

```
Bloodstained: Ritual of the Night
45,29

Portal Knights <-------- **focus on it**
14,79

Unforgiving - A Northern Hymn
5,79
```

And these are (parts of) the results after mapping

```
[{'Bloodstained: Ritual of the Night', '45,29'},
 {'14,79', 'Portal Knights'}, <-------- **same as before**
 {'Unforgiving - A Northern Hymn', '5,79'},
 ...
 {'MovieMator Video Editor Pro - Movie Maker, Video Editing Software', '14,48'}]
```

The whole code is below

```
from soup import make_soup
from pprint import pprint

def create_dict(elem):
    title = elem.find('span', {'class': 'title'}).text
    price = elem \
        .find('div', {'class': 'search_price'}) \
        .text.split('R$')[-1].strip()

    print(title)
    print(price)
    print('')
    return {title, price}


url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=weeklongdeals'
soup = make_soup(url)

result_row_list = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'search_result_row'})

data = map(
    create_dict,
    result_row_list
)


pprint(list(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

well, after read it all again I see the error, I was returning {title, price} as a set, not dict. because set does not have an order, it end up like this. I'm kinda stupid to waste time on it.

I don't know if I erase the question, maybe it can help someone one day. So, you guys decide. thanks, anyway

Comment: Beware dicts now keep the order of insertion upon creation, but [do not rely on it](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation)